# Spring MVC View value not getting updated

Tags: spring, jsp, tomcat

This is just a brief of the issue that I am facing.
I have a url
localhost:8080/app/index.jsp displays list of names from database.

I inserted a new name in the db and refreshed the page.
However, it is not getting reflected instantly, but when I try after a considerable amount of time (in this case approx 30-40 mins), the value is reflected in the UI.

Comment: Are you getting the list from the database server in the index.jsp page itself? Or is there a controller to get this value and show in the index.jsp page?

Comment: Please provide the source code for the *jsp* page and any controllers and configuration behind.

Comment: Can you see new value if you open page in new session (private/incognito mode or another browser)?

Comment: update the question with the code